# Get all types implementing generic interface using Type variable with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have registered many types that implement `IEventListener<T>` interface.

How can I resolve all types that implement `IEventListener<T>` but using only Type variable ?

For example I have event SomethingHappened and two types that implement `IEventListener<SomethingHappened>` interface.

I'm sending event over some EventBus and I receiving it as instance of Object class. How can I resolve all listeners (types that implement `IEventListener<SomethingHappened>` interface) using only result of `GetType()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple way to do it:

1. Resolve listeners by interface.
   You can define the interface you need from its generic definition:

   ```
   var eventType = @event.GetType(); // suppose it's SomethingHappened type
   var eventListenerType = typeof(IEventListener<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
   // eventListenerType is IEventListener<SomethingHappened>
   ```

   Then you can get the implementation you need from whatever you want, from lifetimescope for example.
2. Register EventListeners by the type they listen, Keyed or Metadate registrations for example

   ```
   public static void RegisterMessageHandlers(this ContainerBuilder builder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
   {
       foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
       {
           var eventListeners = assembly.GetTypes().Where(
               t => t.IsClass &&
                    t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventListener<>)));

           foreach (var eventListener in eventListeners)
           {
               var interfaces = eventListener.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventListener<>));

               foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
               {
                   var eventType = @interface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                   builder.RegisterType(eventListener)
                       .As<IEventListener>()
                       .WithMetadata<EventListenerMetadata>(c => c.For(m => m.EventType, eventType));
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can inject all registered event listeners as

   ```
   IEnumerable<Lazy<IEventListener, EventListenerMetadata>> eventListeners
   ```

   And get the event listener you need

   ```
   var listOfEventListeners = eventListeners.Where(x => x.Metadata.EventType == eventType);
   ```